# Issue in Sending multiple result via jquery to php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am sending two values to a php page to print those values in the  div.

Here is my jquery code and i have given the php page below:

### Edit : I have updated the script, But the issue is i am not getting the value of $month from php file

(But i can able to print custom message intead)

**Script :**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
       var month=$("#month").val();   
       var year=$("#year").val();   
       $.post("summaryreport_result.php",
             {month: month, year: year}).done(function(data)

         {

                $('#stage').html(data).fadeIn(1000);
            $('#stage').html(data).fadeOut(3000);
               }

          );
      });
   });
   </script>
```

PHP Code :

```
<?php
 $month=$_REQUEST['month'];
 $year=$_REQUEST['year']; 
 echo $month;

?>
```

But if i print a custom message it is displaying the div stage

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this ?

Comment: I do not see any signs of sending `month` and `year` variables in JS code.

Comment: You update is deadly incorrect. It has syntax errors: `{month: month}).done(function(data) {year: year}).done(function(data)` is something very strange.

Comment: sorry i have updated. And now the problem is php not returning the $month value

Comment: Can you show rendered HTML code?

Comment: check data value  using alert

Comment: Now, issue is solved as there is problem in the allocation of variable for #year

Answer (score 0):

Try this `POST` Request

```
$.post("summaryreport_result.php",
         {month: month, year: year}).done(function(data){

            $('#stage').html(data).fadeIn(1000);
            $('#stage').html(data).fadeOut(3000);
           }

      );
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, i update, but in the php file it's not returning the value of $month

Comment: Can you check your console. data is posting or not

Comment: I can get the first value in the result, but not the second value, any issues in sending the values ? I mean here {month: month, year: year}).done(function(data)

Comment: where are you getting first value in JS or PHP

Comment: I mean i can get the value in fadein, that i am printing in #stage

Comment: Now, the issue is solved, as there is internal variable allocation value for year, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
       var month=$("#month").val();   
       var year=$("#year").val();   
       $.post("summaryreport_result.php",
             {month: month, year: year}).done(function(data)
         {

                $('#stage').html(data).fadeIn(1000);
            $('#stage').html(data).fadeOut(3000);
         });    
      });
   });
   </script>
```